# Explanation needed for strange behaviour of combobox

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox, datasource

I was just writing a windows application that populates three comboboxes from the same datasource. My datasource is a datatable.

The way i populate the comboboxes is by repeating the following code for each of the comboboxes:

```
'populate 1st combobox
cbx1.DataSource = table
cbx1.DisplayMember = "someColumn"
cbx1.ValueMember = "anotherColumn"
cbx1.SelectedIndex = Indx

'populate 2nd combobox
cbx2.DataSource = table
cbx2.DisplayMember = "someColumn"
cbx2.ValueMember = "anotherColumn"
cbx2.SelectedIndex = Indx

'populate 3rd combobox
cbx3.DataSource = table
cbx3.DisplayMember = "someColumn"
cbx3.ValueMember = "anotherColumn"
cbx3.SelectedIndex = Indx
```

When the application is run, and I select an item from the dropdown list of, say, cbx1, my choice is reflected in cbx2 and cbx3 as well. I find this behaviour strange and will be grateful if anybody could explain what is going on here behind the scenes.

On a side note, I've been able to circumvent this problem by modifying my code as shown below, but would still like to have an explanation for this seemingly strange behaviour.

```
'populate 1st combobox
Dim t1 as datatable = table.Copy
cbx1.DataSource = t1
cbx1.DisplayMember = "someColumn"
cbx1.ValueMember = "anotherColumn"
cbx1.SelectedIndex = Indx

'populate 2nd combobox
Dim t2 as datatable = table.Copy
cbx2.DataSource = t2
cbx2.DisplayMember = "someColumn"
cbx2.ValueMember = "anotherColumn"
cbx2.SelectedIndex = Indx

'populate 3rd combobox
Dim t3 as datatable = table.Copy
cbx3.DataSource = t3
cbx3.DisplayMember = "someColumn"
cbx3.ValueMember = "anotherColumn"
cbx3.SelectedIndex = Indx
```

Comment: @Jose: Yes, it is a windows application

Comment: The table instance is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is not so strange - you have three combo boxes all bound to the same data source, so when you select a value in the first combo box, you are changing the index of the current record in the underlying data source - since the other two combo boxes are bound to this, they will update also.

**Edit:** Behind the scenes, the reason for the behaviour is to do with how data binding is implemented in the .Net framework - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482/winforms-combobox-data-binding-gotcha) for a more detailed explanation.

As you have discovered, the solution is to use separate data sources for each combo box. There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344366/multiple-combo-boxes-with-the-same-data-source-c) which you may find interesting.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and the links, the behaviour is now clear to me

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have assigned the same instance of the datatable to the comboboxes.

Comment: Yes, I suspected as much, that's why I was able to circumvent it the way I did. However, I'm more interested in what happens behind the scenes for it to exhibit such behaviour. I thought that selecting an item in the combobox shouldn't affect its datasource.