# Independent drop down lists with shared data source

Tags: c#, .net

I have binding list:

```
BindingList<string> sampleList = new BindingList<string>();
sampleList.Add("aaa");
sampleList.Add("bbb");
```

used as data source for two combo boxes:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = sampleList;
comboBox2.DataSource = sampleList;
```

When I change selection in one of these combo boxes, second is affected as well. How can I keep them independent?

EDIT:

Due to some 'hot' comments I have to do some clarifications:

- it is windows forms code
- it is possible
- there is no another logic / code behind it
- I'm using .NET 2.0

full code source:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<string> sampleList;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        sampleList = new BindingList<string>();
        sampleList.Add("aaa");
        sampleList.Add("bbb");

        comboBox1.DataSource = sampleList;
        comboBox2.DataSource = sampleList;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not possible, because BindingList has no information about a selected item in a combobox. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Can you provide code for changing the selected value?

Comment: One can wonder. People are incredibly quick to use the downvotes these days.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess, because a lot of info is missing. As I already commented, what the OP implies is just not true and his problem must be in code he isn't showing.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, A reasonable comment. What I implied with mine was that people are quick to downvote without waiting for a clarification. They expect perfect questions off the bat.

Comment: @Steen: agree. I think in case of downvoting user have to be "forced" to provide at least some comments on it. It's not just Like/Dislike of  social network.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinForms ComboBox data binding gotcha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482/winforms-combobox-data-binding-gotcha)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
comboBox1.DataSource = sampleList.ToList();
comboBox2.DataSource = sampleList.ToList();
```

Comment: Pardon me, but what would be the reason of using BindingList<T> at all, then?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I know what ToList() means. But why use BindingList<T> at all, if he's supposed to call ToList() on it and disregard the BindingList<T> type?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use yours solution because I am stick in .NET 2.0 while ToList() method is available from .NET 3.5 ;-/

Comment: @Steen It will create a list as a Seperate list from the samplelist

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Why use a BindingList<T> at all? Why not simply create one List<T> and clone it, if that's your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 separate Data sources. In this particular case 2 different `BindingList` instances per combo, may be the best solution, especially if we are talking about reasonably small lists.

If I'm not mistake every Form has it's default associated `BindingSource` and it, actually, manages the "linking" controls refered to the same collection. But I'm not very sure in this, honestly.

Regards.