# Synchronize a ComboBox with a List<string> [C#]

Tags: c#, winforms, list, combobox, synchronization

Is there any way to synchronize my `List<string>` with a `ComboBox` ?

What I'd like to have is my ComboBox, automaticly updating it's content depending on the List's changes.

I've tried using the `ComboBox.DataSource` property but this doesn't update the ComboBox, it only fills it once and that's all then, so ...

Answer (score 5):

Use [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) object.

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>();
 BindingSource bsource=new BindingSource();

 //Set list dataSource
 bsource.DataSource = list;
 comboBox1.DataSource = bsource;

 //Now add an element via Binding object
 bsource.Add("One");
 bsource.Add("Two");
```

Or you may try [ArrayList.Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.adapter.aspx) method that creates Adapter wrapper of IList.

ArrayList items;

```
items=ArrayList.Adapter(comboBox1.Items);
items.Add("one");
```

Comment: It works using the `BindingSource` object! There's only one problem left : I instanciate many ComboBoxes using this List and all the ComboBoxes are synchronized together so ...

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your `List<string>` with an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

Comment: Do you use Databinding, if so use the ItemsSource property of the combobox

Comment: The thing is that I'm probably using it the bad way... How do you set it as data resource for the ComboBox ? I tried with `.DataSource` it didn't work... And the type isn't accepted if I'm using `.DataBindings` so ... I just tried `ItemsSource`, the property doesn't exist...

Comment: Ok, are we talking about WinForms or WPF?

Comment: I'm using WinForms `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`

Comment: AFAIK this does not work if you´re using WinForms, you have to call combobox.Refresh();

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the sample: [How to: Create and Bind to an ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx).

More information about binding sources: [Binding Sources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx).

**Update:**

Sorry, I have not mention that you're using Windows forms, so please see the question: [WinForms ComboBox data binding gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482/winforms-combobox-data-binding-gotcha).